# Trying to dismiss View Controller that presents SLComposeViewController after user posts to FB in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am presenting an `SLComposeViewController` to post to Facebook in my app.  The user is able to dismiss this View Controller in one of two ways: either by posting their post to Facebook, or by pressing "cancel".  When the user presses "cancel", the `SLComposeViewController` is dismissed, and the user is returned to the presenting View Controller that is behind it.

However, what I would like to do is if the user presses "post", then I want the presenting View Controller to ALSO be dismissed after the `SLComposeViewController` is dismissed (i.e. in the `SLComposeViewControllerResultDone` case).  My problem is that I am not sure how to do this.  I realize that I would use the completion handler for this, but I am stuck here.  Here is the code that I have which presents the `SLComposeViewController`:

```
    SLComposeViewController *fbSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [fbSheet setInitialText:initialText];
    [fbSheet addImage:myImage];

    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

    switch(result){
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
        default:
        {
            NSLog(@"Cancelled.....");

        }
            break;
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
        {
            NSLog(@"Posted....");
        }
            break;
    }

};

[fbSheet setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];

[self presentViewController:fbSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

With the completion handler above, I get the `NSLog` outputs as expected.  However,

Can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong?  As I've pointed out, I need the dismissal of the presenting View Controller to occur ONLY if the user "posts" to Facebook, but NOT when they cancel.

Comment: You could use the completionHandler of SLComposeViewController to know when the user has completedComposing the post. Depending upon result variable, you could dismiss you viewController. For More [Check this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SLComposeViewController/completionHandler)

Comment: @Ad-J Thanks very much for your comment.  I've updated my code above to include your suggestion.  However, I am not sure how to dismiss the calling viewController (i.e. the one that calls SLComposeViewController) once the user has successfully posted to Facebook.

Comment: Check my answer below. It works fine with your provided code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply dismiss the presenting view controller in `SLComposeViewControllerResultDone` part of completionHandler as below:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    });
```

If you are supporting iOS 6, then you need to dismiss the `SLComposeViewController` first.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to dismiss ViewController in the completion handler, it will be handled when you press cancel button

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    SLComposeViewController * fbSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [controller setInitialText:initialText];
    [fbSheet addImage:myImage];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];        
}
```

Comment: I need to dismiss the View Controller that presents the SLComposeViewController if the user "posts" to Facebook.