# IOS/Objective-C: Dismiss view controller after SLComposer message

Tags: ios, objective-c, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying dismiss a view controller after the SLComposer sends a message.

To do this, I'm using the completion block in the SLComposer method as follows:

```
  [myPostSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

            switch (result) {


        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Post Canceled");
            [self alertPostFail];
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                NSLog(@"Post Successful");
                success = 1;
                [self dismissUnderlyingVC ];

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }];

-(void)dismissUnderlyingVC {
    LogDebug(@"trying to dismiss Underlying VC");
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However, despite my putting the dismissal in the completion block, it is firing before the SLComposer is actually dismissed, is not dismissing the next VC down and is giving following error:

```
     -[myVC dismissUnderlyingVC][Line 227] [DEBUG]
 trying to dismiss Underlying VC
    2018-08-28 20:23:59.579416-0400 idaru[1772:662392]
 [core] SLComposeViewController skipping explicit 
dismiss because isBeingDismissed is already 1
    2018-08-28 20:23:59.588142-0400 
idaru[1772:662392] [core] SLComposeViewController dealloc
```

I gather that the SLComposer does not have a delegate so wondering how I can ascertain that it has actually been dismissed so that I can dismiss the next VC below it.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to dismiss View Controller that presents SLComposeViewController after user posts to FB in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664399/trying-to-dismiss-view-controller-that-presents-slcomposeviewcontroller-after-us)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view controller is currently presenting the `SLComposeViewController`.

So, when you call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` on `self`, you're actually asking to dismiss the `SLComposeViewController` (which is already in the process of being dismissed).

Try asking the `presentingViewController` to dismiss instead:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```